# EdiFabric - Change separator from caret to colon (or any change of separator)

Tags: edi, edifabric

This applies to EdiFabric 6.7.2.

In the code below, I'm loading a list in an 837 EDI format on a D_1328_7 field.

When the EDI is output the `List<string>` is arranged with a caret (^) separator.  I've been informed by the consumer of my EDI 837 file that the separator must be a colon (`:`).

For the life of me I can't figure out how to change it, or even where the caret separator comes from.

```
object837.G_HL[_heirachy_HL_Index].G_CLM[_HL_G_CLM_Index].G_LX[_LX_Index].S_SV1.D_1328_7 = new List<string>();
object837.G_HL[_heirachy_HL_Index].G_CLM[_HL_G_CLM_Index].G_LX[_LX_Index].S_SV1.D_1328_7.Add(_diagnosisPointer1);
object837.G_HL[_heirachy_HL_Index].G_C

LM[_HL_G_CLM_Index].G_LX[_LX_Index].S_SV1.D_1328_7.Add(_diagnosisPointer2);
```

OUTPUT =  `SV1*HC:98940*75*UN*1*11**1^2**N**`

Note the caret between 1 and 2.

Comment: ask on EdiFabric mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using and which 837 transaction ?
The caret '^' is the default repetition separator for X12. When you generate EDI you can specify explicitly which separators to use by setting the InterchangeContext in ToEdi(InterchangeContext context = null)

Comment: I was using 6.7.n -I did see where I can change the default separator in MyISA but (I think) the problem is I just want that one separator to change (not all).  And I don't understand what you mean about setting InterchangeContext to null.  Could you elaborate?  (thanks)